# Guice and VertX injectable request context available throught the application

Tags: java, dependency-injection, scope, guice, vert.x

I have been trying to learn ins and outs of VertX Web framework for the past couple of months. 
I have however came across a problem which I thought would be easily solvable - but to this day I haven't been able to find the solution.

So my problem is:
I would like to have a web request scoped context to be injectable through out the application.

What I tried doing is something like this:

```
router.route("...").handler(RoutingContext ctx -> {
    val requestContext = new AppContext(UUID.randomUUID());
    val scope = injector.getInstance(CustomScope.class);
    scope.enter();
    scope.seed(IAppContext.class, requestContext);

    ctx.next();
});

router.route("...").handler(RoutingContext ctx -> {
    // actual code

    ctx.next();
});

router.route("...").handler(RoutingContext ctx -> {
    val scope = injector.getInstance(CustomScope.class);
    scope.exit();

    ctx.response().end();
});
```

I do have a feeling that current solution won't work with multiple requests comming in at the same time. Because VertX runs on a single thread I have to finish the scope before I could enter a new one so this solution is not ok for now.

Guice custom scope is the same as [this](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes) one so if I can fix this in this custom scope code it would be just perfect. I don't know much about these custom scopes so I'm kinda lost on this front...

I would just like to have some request storage somewhere without having to pass it as a parameter to methods all over the application code. I've search around for some way to statically access RoutingContext but no luck for now.

Comment: Why don't you use the Vert.x provided Context Data? http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/scala/#_context_data

Comment: @michalsamek - I would like to have request data available everywhere in the application without passing it around. For example with dependency injection or by statically accessing it (Vertx.CurrentRequestContext?).

Comment: @BizzyDizzy, did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @brunobastosg No sry I didn't.

Comment: @BizzyDizzy why can't you just register one handler for your route and do enter and exit your scope within the handler, while doing the actual logic in between?